# Redirect window.location not working properly

Tags: javascript, timeout

Currently I'm facing a problem with `window.location` method. Because it's redirecting the user immediately to another page and is not reaching my `if (remaining_time <= 1)`. I'd like some help with that. I've `timeout( )` method with `clearInterval( )` to reset it once an event handler is reached but it did not work at all.

***This is my code:***

```
function debounce(func, wait) {
    let timer = null;
    return function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(func, wait);
    }
}


class ActivityDetector {

    constructor(properties={
        timeout: 15,
        checkInterval: 10,
        onTimeout: null,
        onInterval: null,
        onReset: null,
        repeat: false,
        cookieName: 'last_activity',
        cookieDomainName: null,
        cookiePath: ''
    }) {

        this.timeout = properties.timeout;  // Time until event in seconds
        this.checkInterval = properties.checkInterval;  // Interval between checks in seconds
        this.onTimeout = properties.onTimeout;
        this.onInterval = properties.onInterval;
        this.onReset = properties.onReset;
        this.repeat = properties.repeat;
        this.sessionName = properties.sessionName;

        this.enable = debounce(this.enable.bind(this), 100);
        this.disable = debounce(this.disable.bind(this), 100);
        this.reset = debounce(this.reset.bind(this), 100);

        this.interval = null
        this.enable()
      }

    updateLastActivity() {
        this.lastActivity = Date.now() / 1000 | 0;
        window.localStorage.setItem(this.sessionName, this.lastActivity);
        document.cookie = 'last_activity=' + this.lastActivity + '; path=/';
    }

    getLastActivity() {
        this.lastActivity = window.localStorage.getItem(this.sessionName);
        return this.lastActivity;
    }

    enable() {
        const sharedTime = window.localStorage.getItem(this.sessionName);
        let now = Date.now() / 1000 | 0;
        this.lastActivity = sharedTime || now;

        if (!this.interval) {
            this.interval = setInterval(() => {this.check()}, this.checkInterval*1000);

            window.addEventListener("mousemove", this.reset, false);
            window.addEventListener("keypress", this.reset, false);
            window.addEventListener("keyDown", this.reset, false);
            window.addEventListener("mousedown", this.reset, false);
            window.addEventListener("touchstart", this.reset, false);
            window.addEventListener("touchmove", this.reset, false);
            window.addEventListener("mousewheel", this.reset, false);
        }
    }

    disable() {
        if (!!this.interval) {
            window.removeEventListener("mousemove", this.reset, false);
            window.removeEventListener("keydown", this.reset, false);
            window.removeEventListener("keypress", this.reset, false);
            window.removeEventListener("mousedown", this.reset, false);
            window.removeEventListener("touchstart", this.reset, false);
            window.removeEventListener("touchmove", this.reset, false);
            window.removeEventListener("mousewheel", this.reset, false);
            clearInterval(this.interval);
            this.interval = null;
        }
    }

    dispatchTimeout() {
        if (!this.repeat) {
            this.disable();  // Disable new checks if not repeat
        }
        this.updateLastActivity();
        this.onTimeout();
    }

    check() {
        const now = Date.now() / 1000 | 0;
        const timePassed = now - this.getLastActivity();
        const remaining = this.timeout - timePassed
        this.onInterval(remaining);

        if (remaining <= 0) {
            this.dispatchTimeout()
            return
        }
    }

    reset() {
        this.onReset();
        this.updateLastActivity();
    }

}

let activityDetector = new ActivityDetector({
            timeout: 15,
            checkInterval: 1,
            onInterval: (remaining_time) => {
                if (remaining_time <= 1) {
                    window.location = "/auth/logout/";
                } else {
                    document.getElementById('timer').style.display = "contents";
                    document.getElementById('text').innerText = remaining_time;    
                }
            },
            onTimeout: () => {
                console.log(Date.now());
                console.log('End');
            },
            onReset: () => {
                console.log('Reset');
            }
        });
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**Describe the problem**. "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question."_

Comment: _"I'm facing a problem with `window.location` method"_ - `window.location` is an object and not a method.

Comment: far too much code for a [mcve]